# Why calling a function that accepts no parameters with a parameter compiles in C but doesn't in C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

Suppose I have this function:

```
void func() {}
```

When I call `func` with some parameters (e.g. `func(132)`), the `C++` compiler yields an error, while the `C` compiler doesn't.

What is the difference between the two compilers in this case? And what advantages/disadvantages the `C++` has by arising this error?

Comment: It is good practice never compiling with gcc without `-Wall` flag.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: `-Wall` won't catch this, because it doesn't include `-Wstrict-prototypes`.  I use `-Wall -Wextra -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes`, but everyone has their personal set of warning flags they like.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are no advantages or disadvantages.  C supports this for compatibility with K&R C from the 1980s.  You might like this feature if you are still using code you wrote in the 1980s.  You might dislike this feature if you want better diagnostics from your compiler.

```
void func();
```

In C, this means that `func` takes *unspecified* parameters.

If you need to specify that the function takes *no* parameters, write it this way:

```
void func(void);
```

In C++ the two prototypes are the same.  (In C, only the second one is a prototype.)  If you compile with GCC/Clang's `-Wstrict-prototypes` option, you will get warnings for using `void func();` in C, as you should.

This is only about **function declarations.**  In both languages, the following function **definitions** are the same:

```
// These two are the SAME
void func() { }
void func(void) { }

// These two are DIFFERENT
void func();
void func(void);
```

Comment: Like main() can be with argument or without?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: This question is actually about declarations, and since you don't declare `main()`, that's actually a separate question.  However, you can define main as `int main()`, which is the exact same as `int main(void)`, or you can define it as `int main(int, char**)` or some compatible manner, or you can define it in some other, implementation-defined manner.  Lots of choices.  In C you don't even have to return a result from `main()` even though it should return `int` otherwise.

Comment: Actually for the gcc options I think that `-std=c99 -Wall` should suffice to get the diagnostic.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Which version of GCC are you using?  I'm not getting the warning on 4.7.2.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, sorry, I must have mixed up things.

Comment: +1, but the wording of your answer is a bit confusing, since all definitions are necessarily declarations.

Comment: @ruakh: Were you honestly confused?  Or do you think it might be confusing to something else?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I honestly *am* confused, present tense! Or I might be, I'm not sure. I *think* you're saying that even in C, `void func() { }` specifically declares the function as taking no parameters, even though `void func();` does not. Is that right? (I guess that makes sense, since if there *were* any parameters, even K&R C would require something like `void func(a, b) { }`. But it's confusing.)

Comment: @ruakh: Yes, that's right.  `void func() { }` declares the function as taking no parameters, even though `void func();` does not.  Fortunately, we can safely ignore this part of the language when writing new code.

Answer (score 8):

In C++, that function has no arguments. In C, it means an indeterminate number of arguments.

This is a holdover from the very earliest days of C where every function returned an `int` and it was much more relaxed about arguments being passed.